# How can I set a mutable variable in C extensions which takes another C extension as input?

Tags: python, class, cython, static-typing

Let's suppose that there are some classes like these ones:

```
cdef class parent:
  cdef public:
    int trait1
  def __init__(self, num1):
    self.trait1 = num1

cdef class child(parent):
  cdef public:
    int trait2
  def __init__(self, num1, num2):
    super().__init__(num1)
    self.trait2 = num2

cdef class new_parent:
  cdef public:
    float new_trait
  def __init__(self, num):
    self.new_trait = num
```

Now I want to have another class like this one:

```
cdef class gui:
  cdef public:
    parent agent
  def __init__(self, agent):
    self.agent = agent
  def change_parent(self, new_agent): # new_agent could be any of [child, parent, new_parent]
    self.agent = new_agent
    print(self.module)
```

In `gui` class I declare a variable which could get a class as input (between [parent, new_parent, child]). The problem is that if I want to change the `gui.agent` to another class in `gui.change_parent` function, this error occurs:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert _cython_magic_b6858e13e41432c14dc63fbb10e81472.new_parent to _cython_magic_b6858e13e41432c14dc63fbb10e81472.parent
```

I had developed the same code in python but such error never happened because I don't need to static-type the class variables. so what should I do to be able to modify the `gui.agent` to another classes in cython? Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define the type of `agent` to be `parent`, which allows it to be `parent` or any derived type. `new_parent` is not of type `parent` and does not derive from `parent` so can't be assigned to `agent`.

You either need to make `new_parent` inherit from `parent`, or you need to remove the type specifier  on `agent` so that it can accept any Python object (e.g. `object agent`).

What you can't do is specify a fixed Cython type for a variable, and then hope to be able to assign any arbitrary type to that variable.

Comment: So you mean in `gui` class I don't necessarily need to use `cdef public: parent agent`, because it would be detected as a python object. I thought I have to declare every class variable in cython classes

Comment: You need to declare that the variable exists, but you can declare that it can be any Python object by doing `cdef public: object agent` (I think `cdef public: agent` works too).

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot bro.